# How to implement a null object?

Tags: c++

### Details

I found some information about the *Null Object Pattern* here (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152094/null-pointers-vs-null-object-pattern) and here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern#C.2B.2B).

However, the C++ implementation doesn't illustrate my use case.

I also saw the related link for *Nullable Type* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type).

### Use Case

I have an object that is not part of a hierarchy and wouldn't normally be allocated on the heap. Furthermore, there isn't a convenient value that can be used as a sentinel to indicate *null*. Hopefully, the following code makes the use case clear.

```
class ContrivedType
{
public:
    ContrivedType() :
        mValue(0)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    bool operator==(const ContrivedType& other) const
    {
        return mValue == other.mValue;
    }

    void setValue(std::uint16_t value)
    {
        mValue = value;
    }

private:
    // All values in the range [0, 65535] are valid for use
    std::uint16_t mValue;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    const ContrivedType getValue() const
    {
        return mValue;
    }

    void setValue(const ContrivedType &value)
    {
        mValue = value;
    }

private:
    ContrivedType mValue;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;

    if (f.getValue() == ContrivedType())
    {
        // Ambiguous case
        // -    Was this value explicitly set to be the same value
        //      as when it's default constructed
        // OR
        // -    Was the value never set
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Possible Solution 1

Force users of the `ContrivedType` that need to disambiguate between the default state and *unset* to use pointers and dynamically allocate the `ContrivedType`. Perhaps something like this?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() :
        mValue(nullptr)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    const ContrivedType* getValue() const
    {
        return mValue.get();
    }

    void setValue(const ContrivedType &value)
    {
        if (!mValue)
        {
            mValue.reset(new ContrivedType(value));
        }
        else
        {
            *mValue = value;
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ContrivedType> mValue;
};
```

Now it's very clear whether the `ContrivedType` was set or not.

### Possible Solution 2

Update the implementation of the `ContrivedType` to support the concept of *null*.

```
class ContrivedType
{
public:
    ContrivedType() :
        mState(nullptr)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    explicit ContrivedType(std::uint16_t value) :
        mState(&mStorage)
    {
        mStorage.mValue = value;
    }

    bool isNull() const
    {
        return mState == nullptr;
    }

    bool operator==(const ContrivedType& other) const
    {
        if (!isNull())
        {
            return mStorage.mValue == other.mStorage.mValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return other.isNull();
        }
    }

    void setValue(std::uint16_t value)
    {
        mStorage.mValue = value;

        if (!mState)
        {
            mState = &mStorage;
        }
    }

private:
    struct State
    {
        // All values in the range [0, 65535] are valid for use
        std::uint16_t mValue;
    };

    State mStorage;

    // This will point to the storage when a value actually set
    State* mState;
};
```

### Question

Is there an established pattern or idiom for this concept? If not are there any recommendations for implementing it?

### Rationale

In the real code there are classes with 1 ore more members which are *optional* in some contexts. These classes are being serialized over a socket using a protocol that supports fields that are *missing* (i.e., the optional fields). Instead of wasting bytes serializing a default constructed object that wasn't explicitly set the serialization could skip over the *optional* fields. For example, an `updateFoo(const Foo&)` function. If only a subset of an existing`Foo` instance is being updated then only those fields need to be serialized.

### Edit

It looks like `std::experimental::optional` (brought to my attention by @myaut) is what I would want to use but I don't have access to it.

For now I would need to use a solution that would work with Visual Studio 2013 (2015 is probably okay) and g++ 4.8.

Comment: Probably you should take a look at [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)

Comment: @myaut Thank you, I'm not familiar this but I will look into it.

Comment: I think you don't see this pattern implemented in C++ is because it's not needed. in Java and C# , it is very common to return null as an invalid result. since everything in Java/C# is  allocated in the heap (even primitives are wrapped automatically as object) , null can be returned from every function. in C++ , it is not possible to return null on functions that don't return a pointer. you must throw an exception or handle the invalidness in some other way than to return null. this is way C++ developers do not return null object- simply because C++ handle invalidness by other means .

Comment: @DavidHaim I'm not trying to assert you're wrong by asking the following questions, I'm just curious. What is the point of `std::optional` if this isn't needed in C++? I definitely want to know the distinction so should I handle this in C++? Are you suggesting _Option 1_?

Comment: @DavidHaim I added a _Rationale_ section to explain why I'm interested in this concept.

Comment: I don't know exactly why they're discussing this kind of feature , but anyway - if you have an invalid -return value or other kind of error simply throw an exception and handle it somewhere out of the function. just to make clear - returning null as an invalid value is NOT A GOOD PRACTICE. I have seen a lot of Java code, basically , because of this practice every function begins in a null check because no-one knows if the other developer returned null or not . if they threw exception every time they had invalidness , the code was much cleaner

Comment: also, I wouldn't take every suggestion of the committee as a word from god. if they thought seriously what we are missing in our C++ lives, we would have threads , sockets and GUI years ago.

Comment: @DavidHaim I don't know if you've read my _Rationale_ section yet or not but I'm not interested in this for return values.

Comment: I read it only now. the relationship between null object pattern and your problem is very thin. it is ok to keep pointers as a member variables and null them if it's needed. null object speaks of returning an object which symbolizes "invalid object" so other functions will know how to handle it without getting null pointer exception . I also suggest you reading about std::tuple which may also come handy for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74531/discussion-between-james-adkison-and-david-haim).

Comment: @DavidHaim: Actually even in Java this may be considered harmful (i.e. Robert Martin opposes to that in his "Clean Code" book).

Comment: 0 to 65535 in an uint8_t? Good luck with that.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, that's not going to work. :) I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474434/no-optional-in-ms-visual-studio-2013-what-to-do/31484920#31484920) (think to upvote it ;):

> [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) originates from the [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) library, and this implementation works well in Visual C++ 12.0 (though it differs [a little](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html#comparison_with_boost)). Reference single-header implementation, based on the [N3793](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) proposal paper, can be found [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional).
>
> The latest list of supported C++11/14/1z core and library features that are shipped with Visual Studio can be found from the [Visual C++ Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/), from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx) in particular. A set of header files of the Standard Library implementation (and some extensions) from Microsoft can be viewed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx).

I had it a taste recently, with a bit of effort for building it, I manage to use it and was happy with it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I ended up implementing my own `Optional` class.

Comment: @JamesAdkison That's great! you could answer your own question with your implementation of `Optional` :)