# No <optional> in MS Visual Studio 2013 - what to do?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++14, option-type, std, c++17

I want to use `std::experimental::optional`, but MSVS 2013 tells me it can't find the  header.

- Why isn't it there?
- Can I roll my own based on code elsewhere? The C++14 proposal maybe?

Comment: [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/

Comment: Have you tried to roll your own?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Please make that into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Yakk: No, because I know there's a lot of corner-case functionality and a bunch of design decisions I'm not the best person to make. There are reference implementations already, better use one of them.

Comment: FTR there is no spec for `<optional>`, but there is a TS draft for `<experimental/optional>`—somewhat similar to how there was a `<tr1/functional>` (that not all C++ implementations chose to implement) before there was a `<functional>` (which is part of the Standard proper).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) originates from the [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) library, and this implementation works well in Visual C++ 12.0 (though it differs [a little](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html#comparison_with_boost)). Reference single-header implementation, based on the [N3793](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) proposal paper, can be found [here](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional).

The latest list of supported C++11/14/1z core and library features that are shipped with Visual Studio can be found from the [Visual C++ Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/), from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx) in particular. A set of header files of the Standard Library implementation (and some extensions) from Microsoft can be viewed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx).

Comment: please leave comments when downvoting

Comment: You didn't quite answer why std::optional<T> is not in VC++. None of the links even mentions optional.

Comment: @ОгњенШобајић it's clear that this is a C++1z library, would you expect an explanation that back in 2013 noone predicted that there'll be a proposal for adding `optional` to C++1z (presumably, C++17 -> 2017) ?

Comment: I came here searching for `std::experimental::optional` in VS2015. It's still not in there, is it?

Comment: @Ela782 Same, I cant seem to find it despite all the time that has passed

Comment: @Ela782 Same for me. By googling, I found a [blog response](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/08/24/c1417-features-and-stl-fixes-in-vs-15-preview-4/) by Stephan T. Lavavej, where he definitely states: _"I can tell you that std::optional has been implemented and will appear in the next build of VS “15”, it just barely missed the deadline for Preview 4)"_ So hopefully it will be available with the next VS 2015 update.

Comment: @Alatau: Thanks. VS "15" is the **next** VS though, not VS 2015. This probably means that most likely it'll not come to VS 2015, but definitely be in the next VS release.

Comment: VS 2017 RC is now out, with support for `<optional>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this implementation compiles with MSVC2013. Note that only compiles, everything else isn't guaranteed.

https://github.com/mapbox/variant/blob/master/include/mapbox/optional.hpp

Answer (score -1):

I was using this one for msvc2015 and it worked:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akrzemi1/Optional/master/optional.hpp