# How to call derived class function (based on its type) from a container which contain pointer of base class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I inherit from Base class to create two different Derived class ( Derived1 and Derived2), then I place them into a vector. Lets say I want to call the function of Derived class based on the type of class.

pseudocode:

```
if holder[1] stored Derived1 then I want to call GetZ() 
else if holder[1] stored Derived2 then I want to GetFlag().
```

An attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base {
 public:
  Base(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}

  int GetX() { return x_; }
  int GetY() { return y_; }

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
 public:
  Derived1(int x, int y, int z) : Base(x, y), z_(z) {}

  int GetZ() { return z_; }

 private:
  int z_;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
 public:
  Derived2(int x, int y, bool flag) : Base(x, y), flag_(flag) {}

  bool GetFlag() { return flag_; }

 private:
  bool flag_;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> holder;
void print();
int main() {
  holder.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived1>(3, 4, 5));
  holder.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived2>(6, 7, true));

  print();
}

void print(){

  for(auto& it : holder){
    // call this if "it" is Derived2
    // else call it->GetX()
    // currently this gives compilation error 
    // because of object slicing
    std::cout << it->GetFlag() << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you cannot write your classes in a way that they offer a similar interface then polymorphism is likely not the best approach.

Comment: Another possibility would be a visitor pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(auto& it : holder){
  if (auto* D1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(it->get())) {
    std::cout << D1->GetZ();
  } else if (auto* D2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(it->get())) {
    std::cout << D2->GetFlag();
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

dynamic cast is usually code smell, evidence that your interface `Base` is missing functionality.  Once you dynamic cast, your interface goes from what `Base` states to the layout and contents of your entire type heirarchy.

Instead, add:

```
virtual boost::optional<int> GetZ() { return {}; }
virtual boost::optional<bool> GetFlag() { return {}; }
```

to `Base`, and override in derived.

```
for(auto& it : holder){
  if (auto Z = it->GetZ()) {
    std::cout << *Z;
  } else if (auto flag = it->GetFlag())
    std::cout << *flag;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

now we no longer care which specific derived type we used to implement `Z` or `Flag`.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31484920/1774667) there is a [link to a reference std::optional implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional) that uses the boost software license and is one header file.

Comment: @vantamula Yes, you can write yourself an implementation of `optional`.  Or get C++17 `std::optional`.  Or find one from somewhere.

Comment: I know this question is little off topic .. but can you point me in right direction for implementation of my own `optional`.

Comment: @vantamula What I did was I took one of the the proposed papers for C++17 optional and duplicated the parts of the interface I needed.  Then I wrote it.  The hard part in a simple implementation is placement new in a `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: @vantamula Link added to a reference implementation of std::optional with a reasonable license (boost license).  You probably want to munge it a bit so it doesn't live in `std` however.  It is about 10x-20x more complex than a simple optional I would write would be, but it has more features.

Answer (score 1):

check the good ol' `dynamic_cast` trick – if it's castable, it's of the right type.

Anyway, I'd recommend *not* using this design pattern (check types at runtime and decide based on that), but put the logic into the derived classes; have a common method that either does the one or the other thing:

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}

  int GetX() { return x_; }
  int GetY() { return y_; }

  virtual int do_the_right_thing();

 private:
  int x_;
  int y_;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
 public:
  Derived1(int x, int y, int z) : Base(x, y), z_(z) {}

  int GetZ() { return z_; }

  virtual int do_the_right_thing() { return GetZ() };

 private:
  int z_;
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
 public:
  Derived2(int x, int y, bool flag) : Base(x, y), flag_(flag) {}

  bool GetFlag() { return flag_; }

  virtual int do_the_right_thing() { return GetFlag() };

 private:
  bool flag_;
};


void print(){

  for(auto& it : holder){
    // call this if "it" is Derived2
    // else call it->GetX()
    // currently this gives compilation error 
    // because of object slicing
    std::cout << it->do_the_right_thing() << std::endl;
  }

}
```

The STL-style way of dealing with this would be templates and type traits – but I personally consider that to be a nuisance.

Comment: would it be write to return int while `return GetFlag()` since it is of type `bool` ?

Comment: `GetFlag()` returns a `bool`, which isn't an `int`.  For example, if `boolalpha  != 0`, `bool`'s streamed are printed out as alphabetical.  Your `do_the_right_thing` arguably should take an `std::ostream&`.

Comment: That's indeed very arguable :) yeah, you're right, but the method name indicates what I think is missing here: OP's considerations on what they want the derived class to do! So, I'm very thankful for you spotting my mistake, but then again, it's up to OP to define a sensible interface based on their application's purpose.