# Can I return NULL for vector<double> function?

Tags: c++, vector, null

I have the following function:

```
/* Calculate if there is an intersection with given intial position and 
  direction */
vector<double> intersection(vector<double> startPos, vector<double> direction)
{
   if(there is intersection)
      return (intersection coordinates);
   else {
      return NULL;
   }
}
```

Could I do this and check against `NULL` if an intersection exists:

```
vector<double> v = intersection(pos, dir);
if(v == NULL)
   /* Do something */
else
   /* Do something else */
```

If this is not allowed/bad coding practice, what is another way I may go about this?

Comment: A vector cannot possibly be NULL, but it can be empty().

Comment: Maybe see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29460651/10077

Comment: No. NULL is normally used with a pointer. You could however return an empty vector and verify on the other side if it's empty.

Comment: you could also return a (shared) pointer to a vector, but @NeilButterworth's comment is probably the preferred.

Comment: You have 2 options: `1` return an empty vector. `2` throw an exception, because the function cannot fulfill its promise. It depends on the precise circumstances, which of those is more appropriate.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the suggestion! That did not cross my mind at the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NULL` really is only a concept of pointers.  Since we have a container we can check something else, namely, whether or not the container is `empty`.  If it is then we know we have no elements and if it is not then we know there is stuff to process.  That lets you write code like

```
vector<double> intersection(vector<double> startPos, vector<double> direction)
{
    if(there is intersection)
        return (intersection coordinates);
    else {
        return {}; // this means return a default constructed instance
    }
}
```

and then you can use it like

```
vector<double> v = intersection(pos, dir);
if(v.empty())
    /* Do something */
else
    /* Do something else */
```

---

Also note that if you want to get a set intersection you can use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) and use it like

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <vector>
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <iterator>
> int main()
> {
>     std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
>     std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
>     std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
>     std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());     
>     std::vector<int> v_intersection;     
>     std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
>                           v2.begin(), v2.end(),
>                           std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
>     for(int n : v_intersection)
>         std::cout << n << ' ';
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 5 7
> ```

Comment: But there are instances where an empty vector has a distinct difference from a null value in the code

Comment: In that situation, use a `std::optional<vector<double>>` as the return type.